# Gravity Form list type with muliple column - Prefill

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have gravity form with list type and multiple column enabled like this
[image: See this]

and my front end is

[image: front end]

and i want to prefill the data . what hook should i use here

I am trying to prefill the value. Lets say i have  partname, 23 and partname2 with quantity 230. and i want to prefill